# How to get distinct column value according to a certain column value from datatable?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datatable

This is my Data table:

```
===============================================================    
Question || Qid || Aid || answer_id || subject_id || marks
===============================================================
Q1       || 1   || 1   ||    1      ||     1      || 1   
Q1       || 1   || 2   ||    1      ||     1      || 1
Q1       || 1   || 3   ||    1      ||     1      || 1
Q1       || 1   || 4   ||    1      ||     1      || 1
Q2       || 2   || 5   ||    3      ||     1      || 2   
Q2       || 2   || 6   ||    3      ||     1      || 2
Q2       || 2   || 7   ||    3      ||     1      || 2
Q2       || 2   || 8   ||    3      ||     1      || 2
```

I want to get distinct marks for every question like for question 1 mark is 1 and for question 2 mark is 2, but if I use distinct keyword like below I only get 1 or 2 only once

```
var total = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
             where r.Field<Int64>("subject_id") == 1
             select r.Field<Int64>("marks")).ToList().Distinct();
```

and if I don't use distinct I get marks field 4 times for 1 question.

I don't know much about linq, needs help. How to do this?

Comment: Can you show what the the result you finally want? It's not clear by the description.

Comment: Suppose i have 10 questions and 5 contain 1 marks and other 5 contain 2 marks, then i want 5 times 1 and 5 times 2. But if i use distinct as above i get only 1 time 1 and 1 time 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    var total = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                 where r.Field<Int64>("subject_id") == 1
                 select new { Question = r.Field<string>("Question"), Marks = r.Field<Int64>("marks") }).ToList().Distinct();
    string strC = "";
    foreach (var item in total)
    {
        strC = strC + "<br/>" + "Question: " + item.Question + " Marks: " + item.Marks;

    }
    Response.Write(strC);
```

This will give you output like:

```
Question: Q1 Marks: 1
Question: Q2 Marks: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did it with the help of a senior

```
var total = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
             where r.Field<Int64>("subject_id") == 1
             select new { marks = r.Field<Int64>("marks"), QID = r.Field<Int64>("QID") }).ToList().Distinct();
```

[image: it is showing the marks for particular question id]